# Chart for two ratings based on topic in R - What's going wrong?

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, charts

I'm still new to R and have a project I'm trying to complete for my course. I'm looking to create a chart that shows average patient ratings versus average hospital ratings based on topics.

DATA FILE can be found in my GitHub repository: https://github.com/rachh8283/pt-satisfaction-r-tableau

```
df <- import("clean_file.xlsx")

### Average ratings by topic using SQL

    avg_ratings <- sqldf('SELECT Topic, AVG(PtRating) AS MeanPtRate, AVG(HospRating) AS MeanHospRate
          FROM df
          WHERE Ownership == "Proprietary"
          GROUP BY Topic')

### Remove missing values from dataset. 
I have also tried doing this for the avg_ratings object (data frame?), but that doesn't work either. 

    df <- na.omit(df)

### Here's where I'm getting errors. 
I'm trying to plot the two variables based on topic (another variable). 

    plot(avg_ratings$Topic, avg_ratings$MeanPtRate, main="Average Patient Rating vs Average Hospital Rating by Topic", type = "b", 
         pch=19, col = "red", xlab="Topic", ylab="Rating")
    lines(avg_ratings$Topic, avg_ratings$MeanHospRate, type = "b", pch=18, col = "blue", lty=1)
    legend("topright", legend=c("Patient Rating", "Hospital Rating"), col=c("red", "blue"), 
           lty=1, cex=0.8)
```

Here's the error I'm getting:

```
> plot(avg_ratings$Topic, avg_ratings$MeanPtRate, main="Average Patient Rating vs Average Hospital Rating by Topic", type = "b", 
+      pch=19, col = "red", xlab="Topic", ylab="Rating")
Error in plot.window(...) : need finite 'xlim' values
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In xy.coords(x, y, xlabel, ylabel, log) : NAs introduced by coercion
2: In min(x) : no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf
3: In max(x) : no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf
> lines(avg_ratings$Topic, avg_ratings$MeanHospRate, type = "b", pch=18, col = "blue", lty=1)
Warning message:
In xy.coords(x, y) : NAs introduced by coercion
> legend("topright", legend=c("Patient Rating", "Hospital Rating"), col=c("red", "blue"), 
+        lty=1, cex=0.8)
```

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: Please add a sample of your data so others can reporduce your result and provide a solution. You can use `dput()` function for this.

Comment: Thanks @DominikŻabiński, but I'm not sure how to use that dput() function to do what you're asking. When I do just dput(df), it's a huge amount of data and not sure how that would help here. I added the link to my GitHub repository where I've put the data. Hope that helps.

Comment: Instead of `dput` whole dataset you could `dput` sample that is enough to replicate your problem.

Comment: can you also include a list of packages that your functions are coming from please?

Comment: If your object is a vector, matrix, table, data frame or function and is large, object |> head() |> dput() will help give manageable size output.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, this answer will need some editing pending some clarification. I'm not using the `sqldf` function in the following. I'm also using `ggplot2` because you have that in a tag:

```
library(tidyverse)
hospital_data <- readxl::read_xlsx("pt-satisfaction-r-tableau-main/clean_file.xlsx")
str(hospital_data) # Topic needs to be a factor

# Convert Topic to Factor:
hospital_data <- hospital_data %>% 
  mutate(Topic = forcats::as_factor(Topic))

# Summarise means
hospital_data_summarise <- hospital_data %>% 
  filter(Ownership == "Proprietary") %>% 
  group_by(Topic) %>% 
  summarise(ave_pt_rating = mean(PtRating),
            ave_hosp_rating = mean(HospRating)) %>%
  ungroup()
hospital_data_summarise

# Going with geom point
ggplot(hospital_data_summarise, aes(x = Topic, y = ave_pt_rating)) +
  geom_point() +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, vjust = 0.5, hjust=1))
```

Is this roughly what you are after? You may need to adjust the file pathway in line 2.

Comment: Thank you! This is defnitely getting me closer. I'm still getting an error in the plot:  Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : object 'Topic' not found.  Also, the means are different from what I got in my original code. I think it's because I need just the average ratings for proprietary hospitals (Ownership == "Proprietary"). I'll keep working on it.

Comment: No problem! I included `filter(Ownership == "Proprietary")`. But if you update your question as per the comments, it will be easier to reproduce your error and help you further. Perhaps you want to be using `sqldf` and base plotting?